# returning pointer from factory

Tags: c++, c++11, factory, smart-pointers

What is the best way of returning a pointer from a factory ? Should it be a `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` or just a raw pointer?

Also, I was told, that, one should go for `std::unique_ptr` if there is containment and `std::shared_ptr` if there is aggregation. Is this the correct way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be considering raw pointers only in very special cases, such as passing the pointer across a DLL boundary.

Between `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr`, my opinion is to prefer the latter. This leaves the interface more flexible for your users. They can always convert the returned `unique_ptr` to a `shared_ptr` if they desire to, but more importantly, they can also call `unique_ptr::release` and then manually manage the pointer (maybe not a good idea, but it leaves the option open).

If your factory needs to assign a custom deleter for the returned `unique_ptr`, a difference in behavior between `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` you should be aware of is that the former will not call the deleter if the managed pointer is `nullptr`, but the latter will. So, if your factory may return `nullptr` (maybe as a failure condition), and someone converts the `unique_ptr` to a `shared_ptr`, then make sure the deleter can handle being called with `nullptr` as its argument.

Comment: The factory as far as i know will be responsible only for the creation of the object. If i use a unique_ptr, does it mean that the responsibility is transferred to the clients of the factory. Any insights ? For DLL Boundary, if i use shared_ptr, then custom deleter will be able to call the appropriate destructor, isn't it ?

Comment: @Atul No, `unique_ptr` will automatically delete the managed object when it goes out of scope. Passing raw pointers across a DLL boundary should only be a consideration if you need to maintain a C ABI at the boundary. If that is not a concern, you can pass a `shared_ptr` across the boundary.

Comment: If you do need to use a raw pointer at the DLL boundary, you'd have the DLL export both the factory function that returns raw pointers, and the deleter function that the client must call to destroy the object. Then, in a header that is included by the client, you'd define a wrapper function that calls the exported factory function, and sticks it in a `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` along with a deleter that calls the exported deleter function.

Comment: @Praetorian That sounds really suckish. Why not just add a Destroy method that deletes the object it's called on? Anyway, I've always wondered why people "maintain a C ABI" instead of using an actual interop technology.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly shouldn't return a raw pointer. I think std::unique_ptr and std::shared_ptr are equally fine in most cases. But of course the standard smart pointer classes aren't the only ones. For example, there are classes that implement intrusive reference-counting, and people implement a special smart pointer class to handle them, typically called RefPtr. There are also COM interfaces, for which there is CComPtr.